# Passing array from form inputs using get method

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'm passing an array from form inputs (checkboxes) using the get method.
When doing in ajax, with:

```
var subcat_checked = new Array();
$.each($("input[name='subcategories']:checked"), function() {
    subcat_checked.push($(this).val());
});
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '{% url view-category root_category.slug %}',
    data: {subcat: subcat_checked},
    success: function(result) {
        /* stuff */
    },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

the variable key is 'subcategories' when no checkbox is checked, and 'subcategories[]' when some are checked.

Now, when sending it using a non-ajax form and some checkboxes are checked, the variable key is 'categories' (with no [] at the end).

Since I'd like to use the non-ajax form as a fallback if javascript is disabled, I'd like to have the same key when some checkboxes are checked.

Anybody knows how I can do that?

Thanks

Comment: look at this question "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789755"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a change made in jQuery 1.4+, but you can reverse it with the [`traditional` option](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to get the old non-`[]` serialization, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    traditional: true,
    type: 'GET',
    url: '{% url view-category root_category.slug %}',
    data: {subcat: subcat_checked},
    success: function(result) {
        /* stuff */
    },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

You can read more about the option in [the `$.param()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) (what's ultimately called when passing an object as your `data` property)....but basically it does exactly what you want, leaving the `[]` off.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var subcat_checked = $("input[name='subcategories']:checked").serializeArray();

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '{% url view-category root_category.slug %}',
    data: {subcat: subcat_checked},
    success: function(result) {
        /* stuff */
    },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```