# How to (completely) convert query string into JSON object?

Tags: jquery, json, forms

If I have the following form:

```
<form>
  <input name="foo" value="bar">
  <input name="hello" value="world">
  <input name="animals[]" value="panda">
  <input name="animals[]" value="koala">
  <input name="car[make]" value="Honda">
  <input name="car[origin]" value="Japan">
</form>
```

I do **not** want to use `$("form").serialize()`:

```
foo=bar&hello=world&animals%5B%5D=panda&animals%5B%5D=koalacar&%5Bmake%5D=Honda&car%5Borigin%5D=Japan
```

**Instead, I want this:**

```
{"foo":"bar", "hello":"world", "animals":["panda", "koala"], "car":{"make":"Honda", "origin":"Japan"}}
```

To my understanding, jQuery used to do this, but they switched the `serialize` method to return the GET-style query string.  Is there an easy way to get my desired result?

---

### EDIT

I've updated my original question to include `car[make]` and `car[origin]` examples.  It should be assumed that `foo[bar][baz]` or `foo[bar][baz][bof]` input could appear on the form as well.

Additionally, numerically indexed keys that are specified such as `foo[0]=a`, `foo[1]=b`, `foo[4]=c` should be preserved, e.g.,

```
{ ... "foo":["a", "b", undefined, undefined, "c"] ... }
```

Comment: If I get you right, `.serializeArray()` is what you're looking for (http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/).

Comment: @Quasdunk, `.serializeArray()` does not return the result as specified in my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Convert forms to JSON LIKE A BOSS

Github: **[Follow along on Github](https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object)**

The following code can take work with all sorts of input names; and handle them just as you'd expect.

E.g.,

```
<!-- all of these will work! -->
<input name="honey[badger]" value="a">
<input name="wombat[]" value="b">
<input name="hello[panda][]" value="c">
<input name="animals[0][name]" value="d">
<input name="animals[0][breed]" value="e">
<input name="crazy[1][][wonky]" value="f">
<input name="dream[as][vividly][as][you][can]" value="g">
```

```js
// output
{
  "honey":{
    "badger":"a"
  },
  "wombat":["b"],
  "hello":{
    "panda":["c"]
  },
  "animals":[
    {
      "name":"d",
      "breed":"e"
    }
  ],
  "crazy":[
    null,
    [
      {"wonky":"f"}
    ]
  ],
  "dream":{
    "as":{
      "vividly":{
        "as":{
          "you":{
            "can":"g"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Usage

```
$('#my-form').serializeObject();
```

### The sorcery

```
(function($){
    $.fn.serializeObject = function(){

        var self = this,
            json = {},
            push_counters = {},
            patterns = {
                "validate": /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(?:\[(?:\d*|[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\])*$/,
                "key":      /[a-zA-Z0-9_]+|(?=\[\])/g,
                "push":     /^$/,
                "fixed":    /^\d+$/,
                "named":    /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/
            };


        this.build = function(base, key, value){
            base[key] = value;
            return base;
        };

        this.push_counter = function(key){
            if(push_counters[key] === undefined){
                push_counters[key] = 0;
            }
            return push_counters[key]++;
        };

        $.each($(this).serializeArray(), function(){

            // skip invalid keys
            if(!patterns.validate.test(this.name)){
                return;
            }

            var k,
                keys = this.name.match(patterns.key),
                merge = this.value,
                reverse_key = this.name;

            while((k = keys.pop()) !== undefined){

                // adjust reverse_key
                reverse_key = reverse_key.replace(new RegExp("\\[" + k + "\\]$"), '');

                // push
                if(k.match(patterns.push)){
                    merge = self.build([], self.push_counter(reverse_key), merge);
                }

                // fixed
                else if(k.match(patterns.fixed)){
                    merge = self.build([], k, merge);
                }

                // named
                else if(k.match(patterns.named)){
                    merge = self.build({}, k, merge);
                }
            }

            json = $.extend(true, json, merge);
        });

        return json;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This looks like it would work correctly with the default asp.net MVC model binding, is that correct?

Comment: @Benjamin, that's a try-it-and-see, for me; I'm not too familiar with ASP.NET

Answer (score 6):

You could use ".serializeArray()", and then fix the result:

```
var json = {};
$.each($('form').serializeArray(), function() {
  json[this.name] = this.value;
});
```

Of course you might want to worry about multi-valued fields:

```
var json = {};
$.each($('form').serializeArray(), function() {
  var cur = json[this.name];
  if (cur !== undefined) {
    if ($.isArray(cur))
      cur.push(this.value);
    else
      json[ this.name.replace(/\[[^\]]*\]$/, '') ] = [ cur, this.value ];
  }
  else
    json[this.name] = this.value;
});
```

(*edit* — now that I think about it, "serialize" and "serializeArray" already kind-of deal with multi-value parameters for you, giving you names like "whatever[2]" in the serialized form. It'd work anyway but it might be unnecessary to do anything more than the simple one.)

Comment: This creates json like `{ ... "animals[]":["panda", "koala"]}` where `animals[]` should be `animals`.

Comment: uhh ... huh?  Oh wait; yes I see what you mean.  I'll fix that.

Comment: OK I added a regex to strip those.

Comment: Thanks for working with me on this, I'm still looking for a bit more of a comprehensive solution though.  See edits above.  I did some digging around on this and found a lot of half-assed solutions to this problem.  I suspect this is going to end up with a bounty.

Comment: Well a lot depends on what your server-side code expects to see in the HTTP request.

Comment: Thanks again for illustrating that this was not an easy task.  Nevertheless, with a little extra free time and the help of some others, I was able to get the ball rolling on this.  See the selected answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good answer to convert the querystring to JSON.  I got from the following [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5362723/763747)

```
knovel.util = {
     queryParamsToJson : function (theURL) {
        href = theURL;
        qStr = href.replace(/(.*?\?)/, '');
        qArr = qStr.split('&');
        stack = {};
        for (var i in qArr) {
            var a = qArr[i].split('=');
            var name = a[0],
                value = isNaN(a[1]) ? a[1] : parseFloat(a[1]);
            if (name.match(/(.*?)\[(.*?)]/)) {
                name = RegExp.$1;
                name2 = RegExp.$2;
                //alert(RegExp.$2)
                if (name2) {
                    if (!(name in stack)) {
                        stack[name] = {};
                    }
                    stack[name][name2] = value;
                } else {
                    if (!(name in stack)) {
                        stack[name] = [];
                    }
                    stack[name].push(value);
                }
            } else {
                stack[name] = value;
            }
        }
        return stack;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps some one..

Comment: If you want your blank fields to come out as blank fields rather than NaN, change the line that reads value = isNaN(a[1]) ? a[1] : parseFloat(a[1]); to simply value = a[1]

Answer (score 0):

I always do it like this, maybe a bit long winded but it's easy for me to maintain.

```
function FormContent(foo, hello, animals)
{
    this.Foo = foo;
    this.Hello = hello;
    this.Animals = animals;
}

var animals = [];
$("[name='animals[]']").each(function(){
    animals.push($(this).val());
});

var foo = $("[name='foo']").val();
var hello = $("[name='hello']").val();

var formContent = new FormContent(foo, hello, animals);
var jsonContent = json.stringify(formContent); // from json.org
```

I just realized you specifically asked "using jQuery" sorry. I've never had luck serializing to json with jQuery. Hope this helps anyway.

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help, but this answer is very inflexible and requires reconfiguration for each form/input I use it on.

Comment: I posted a solution here that I think might be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to take a form I had previously serialized using jQuery and convert it into an object, replacing all encoding for special characters, etc. with their literal value. Using Dilip's example here, this is what I used.

```
  Form1 = $('#MyForm').serialize();  // Name=Mr.+John+Mark+Jr.&Email=john%40example.com
  Form1 = Form1.replace(/\+/g, '%20'); // Name=Mr.%20John%20Mark%20Jr.&Email=john%40example.com
  var Decoded = decodeURIComponent(Form1); // Name=Mr. John Mark Jr.&Email=john@example.com
  var Values = queryParamsToJson(Decoded); // { Name : "Mr. John Mark Jr.", Email : "john@example.com" }

  function queryParamsToJson(theURL)
  {
     href = theURL;
     qStr = href.replace(/(.*?\?)/, '');
     qArr = qStr.split('&');
     stack = {};
     for (var i in qArr)
     {
        var a = qArr[i].split('=');
        var name = a[0],
        value = isNaN(a[1]) ? a[1] : parseFloat(a[1]);
        if (name.match(/(.*?)\[(.*?)]/))
        {
           name = RegExp.$1;
           name2 = RegExp.$2;
           //alert(RegExp.$2)
           if (name2)
           {
              if (!(name in stack))
              {
                 stack[name] = {};
              }
              stack[name][name2] = value;
           }
           else
           {
              if (!(name in stack))
              {
                 stack[name] = [];
              }
              stack[name].push(value);
           }
        }
        else
        {
           stack[name] = value;
        }
     }
     return stack;
  }
```

Now I can access any value as "Values.variable"