# GET key value from AJAX response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm making a cross domain call to a php which returns this:

```
response=2&count=15&id=84546379&firstname=adsa&emailstatus=
```

I want to pick out the values of response and id, but not sure how, my code is as follows:

**

```
xhr.request({
                    url: "../promo_getstate2.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {
                      email: emailaddress,
                      country: country,
                      lang: lang,
                      source: '1312_XMAS_dly'
                    }
                }, function(response){
                   getstate = response['response'];
                   regID = response['id'];
                   console.log(getstate)
                    console.log(regID)
})
```

but it's not geting those values. How do I do this?

The response is:

```
" response=2&count=15&id=84546379&firstname=adsa&emailstatus="
```

**

Comment: paste the output for your response, we don't know the format and value of the response.

Comment: check out this http://aameer.github.io/articles/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors/. Hope it helps

Comment: Possible Duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789755/how-can-i-convert-query-string-or-json-object-map-to-single-json-object-with-jqu

Comment: Your response is like this `response=2&count=15&id=84546379&firstname=adsa&emailstatus=`?

Comment: yes well it's  response=2&count=15&id=84546379&firstname=adsa&emailstatus=

Comment: "it's not geting those values" — what is it getting? Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Comment: this question has an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2091331/280539

Comment: @user1937021 you can use dataType:"json" in your ajax request, use it in **success** method like response.response, response.id

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is create a `params` object of all parameters in the response as shown below:

```
function parseResponse(str) {
    var arr = str.split("&");
    var temp, params = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        temp = arr[i].split("=");
        params[temp[0]] = temp[1];
    }
    return params;
}

var values = parseResponse("response=2&count=15&id=84546379&firstname=adsa&emailstatus=")
```

You can then access values as:

`values['response']; // 2`

`values['id']; // 84546379`

Comment: Can you share the string that you pass to the function?

Answer (score 0):

Code as that:

```
<Script language="javascript">
        var vars=GetRequest("response=2&count=15&id=84546379&firstname=adsa&emailstatus=");
        document.write(JSON.stringify(vars));

        function GetRequest(v) {
           var url = "?"+v;//location.search;
           var theRequest = new Object();
           if (url.indexOf("?") != -1) {
              var str = url.substr(1);
              strs = str.split("&");
              for(var i = 0; i < strs.length; i ++) {
                 theRequest[strs[i].split("=")[0]]=unescape(strs[i].split("=")[1]);
              }
           }
           return theRequest;
        }
        </script>
```

Then you can get the values. For example, the json of the result is

```
{"response":"2","count":"15","id":"84546379","firstname":"adsa","emailstatus":""}
```